# Replacing Windows 7 64 bit with Ubuntu 32 bit

Tags: 32-bit

I have an old laptop with 1.5gb RAM and am running Windows 7 64-bit. It is slow. Can I replace this with Ubunut 32-bit or are there problems ie do I need to install Ubuntu 64-bit?Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For RAMs **lesser** than 2GBs it is recommended to use 32-Bit Operating Systems

Use [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to make a bootable image of Ubuntu , once booted use 'Try Ubuntu without installing' option and later on install it into your partition.